# BlockingCollection.IsComplete is never true

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

The .NET BlockingCollection class works really well for me, but for some reason the IsCompleted property always returns false ... even when the BlockingCollection.Count is 0.

```
while (!WorkUnits.IsCompleted)
{
   ... 
   // WorkUnits.Count == 0 but IsCompleted stays false
}
```

As a workaround I can break out of my outer while(!blockingCollection.IsComplete) loop this way:

```
if (WorkUnits.Count == 0 )
{
    break;
}
```

This works, but adds bloat for something that seems like it should already be working, but I suspect I might not understand the IsComplete well enough to be taking advantage of it correctly.

**EDIT:**

Thanks, Mike and Scott! I folded in your suggestions and created a new public GitHub project, [GhostLine](https://github.com/micahlhoover/ghostline).

Comment: You are asking for a threading-race bug.  If the Count is 0 then it is just empty.  The producer hasn't had a chance to add more items.  Not complete, it may well add an item later.  It isn't complete until the producer explicitly says it is complete and promises that it will never again add more elements.

Comment: Just a note, usually using `while (!WorkUnits.IsCompleted)` is a sign you might be doing something wrong with a blocking collection because you are polling for work. A much better solution is often to do `foreach(var item in WorkUnits.GetConsumingEnumerable())` and use `item` in the loop to do the work, the foreach will block when the collection is empty and will leave the loop once `CompleteAdding` has been called and all items removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation of `BlockingCollection` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find the following piece of information:

> A producing thread can call the CompleteAdding method to indicate that no more items will be added. Consumers monitor the IsCompleted property to know when the collection is empty and no more items will be added.

So, do you ever invoke `CompleteAdding` ?